# Viewport width stopping fixed div from scrolling horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am making a mobile webpage that is the height of the mobile screen but scrolls horizontally through its content.

The problem I am running into is that a div with a fixed position will only scroll horizontally until it reaches the viewport width (I have been testing in chrome with device mode enabled and the iPhone 6 selected, which has a viewport width of 375px while my body element has a width of 1875px).

Here is code showing a simplified version of my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1875, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            body{
                width: 1875px;
                margin: 0px;
            }
            div{
                width: 200px;
                position: fixed;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>This is the test paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have found similar questions, but most people are asking how to stop a fixed div from scrolling horizontally, whereas I want the fixed div to scroll the entire width of the body element without stopping at the viewport width.

I would put up a fiddle but I cannot replicate the problem without a device simulation like in the chrome dev tools.

Comment: you can reproduce it [here](https://output.jsbin.com/tivacamava). Really, really weird behavior. You can see funny things when you try to play with `right: 0` or `left: 5000px; margin: -5000px;`, but it still behaves the same.

Comment: It is weird. do you have any ideas for a work around? I just need one element to be stationary in the viewport as I scroll horizontally.

Comment: cannot imagine anything else but setting it to `position: absolute` and by tracking the scrolling event change the `left` property. This will work 100% but looks ugly like hell

Comment: Yes it is quite jumpy, and on mobile you usually get some "momentum" scrolling after a scroll which doesn't fire a touch event to update the `left` property . Thanks, I think I may redesign to make it vertical scrolling instead.

Comment: one more crazy idea... You might try with body rotated by 90 degrees and the content also rotated to -90 degrees using transform :)

Comment: the [results](https://jsbin.com/powapivixa/1/edit?html,output) of that are pretty interesting :). I think I'm going to have to go the `position: absolute` route and make it work. Thanks for the suggestions.